# How do I reference multilevel elements with pure CSS for only one class?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

Using pure css for a horizontal menu.  The [original code](http://www.cssscript.com/create-a-multi-level-drop-down-menu-with-pure-css/) came from cssscript.com:

This is my markup:

```
<ul class="main-navigation">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Front End Design</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Resets</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grids</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Frameworks</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Ajax</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">WordPress Development</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Themes</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Plugins</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Custom Post Types</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Portfolios</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.main-navigation{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: red;
}

.main-navigation ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background: #1bc2a2;
}

/* This hides the dropdowns */


.main-navigation li ul { display: none; }

.main-navigation ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #fff;
}

.main-navigation ul li a:hover { background: #2c3e50; }

/* Display the dropdown */


.main-navigation li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.main-navigation li:hover li { float: none; }

.main-navigation li:hover a { background: #1bc2a2; }

.main-navigation  li:hover li a:hover { background: #2c3e50; }

.main-navigation li ul li { border-top: 0; }

/* Displays second level dropdowns to the right of the first level dropdown */


.main-navigation ul ul ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

/* Simple clearfix */



.main-navigation ul:before,
.main-navigation ul:after {
  content: " "; /* 1 */
  display: table; /* 2 */
}

.main-navigation ul:after { clear: both; }
```

This is the original which works:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #1bc2a2;
}

ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background: #1bc2a2;
}

/* This hides the dropdowns */


li ul { display: none; }

ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #fff;
}

ul li a:hover { background: #2c3e50; }

/* Display the dropdown */


li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

li:hover li { float: none; }

li:hover a { background: #1bc2a2; }

li:hover li a:hover { background: #2c3e50; }

.main-navigation li ul li { border-top: 0; }

/* Displays second level dropdowns to the right of the first level dropdown */


ul ul ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

/* Simple clearfix */



ul:before,
ul:after {
  content: " "; /* 1 */
  display: table; /* 2 */
}

ul:after { clear: both; }
```

My concern is this will style other ul li, etc. if I use them elsewhere in the page.  They will have nothing to do with the menu.  How can I reference these styles for use with only the menu?

Comment: Can someone please explain why this received a downvote?  I really want to ask correctly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A white space, in CSS selectors, define a descendant hierarchy, so when you changed this:

```
ul li {
```

To this:

```
.main-navigation ul li {
```

You were looking for a list item, inside an `ul` tag, that is inside an element with the `.main-navigation` class.

Instead, for it to work, you need to replace the root `ul` definition of the original stylesheet, with the main class selector:

```
.main-navigation {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #1bc2a2;
}

.main-navigation li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  background: #1bc2a2;
}

/* This hides the dropdowns */


.main-navigation li ul { display: none; }

.main-navigation li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #fff;
}

/* And so on.... */
```

Please let me know if you need further clarification.